# Protecting a method from returning nil on a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tagging

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.tagged_with(name)
    recipes = Tag.find_by(name: name).recipes
  end
end
```

In controller

```
def tag
  @recipes = Recipe.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  render 'index'
end
```

Routes

```
get 'tag/:tag', to "recipes#tag"
```

How can I protect this method from breaking? If I search for a tag that hasn't been created, I get a noMethodError 'recipes' for nil:NilClass. I have tried putting

```
return false if recipes.nil?
```

as well as

```
redirect_to(recipes_path) if recipes.nil?
```

at the end of the method but nothing as worked.

Comment: `if recipes && recipes.nil?`

Answer (score 1):

It throws that error because when the value returned by `Tag#find_by` is `nil`, it cannot call the method `recipes` on it. In other words, `nil` doesn't have a `recipes` method.

Try checking if the tag exists first, with something like:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.tagged_with(name)
    tag = Tag.find_by(name: name)
    recipes = tag.recipes unless tag.nil?
  end
end
```

I don't know the way you organized your data, but a better way would be something like this probably:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Recipe.find_by(tag: name)
  end
end
```

Comment: i don't have a tag column and I tried your first suggestion already and it doesn't work

Comment: @Kohl, what doesn't work exactly? Can you tell me the error message.

Comment: no worries, I figured it out. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.tagged_with(name)
     tag = Tag.find_by(name: name)
     if !tag.nil?
        recipes = tag.recipes 
     else
        return false
     end

end
```

In Controller:

```
def tag
 @recipes = Recipe.tagged_with(params[:tag]) 
 if @recipes != false
  render 'index'
 else
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You see NoMethodError because you call method `recipies` on NilClass.`find_by` method returns `nil` if nothing found (by the way, `find` would raise an exception, and `where` return empty relation)
So, first you can do is to use `try`:
`

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.tagged_with(name)
    recipes = Tag.find_by(name: name).try(:recipes)
  end
end
```

`try` will silently return `nil`
But then you could use a better approach with `scope` (assuming you have `tags` relation):

`

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  scope :tagged_with, ->(name) { joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: name }) }
end
```

Probably, you then want to call `uniq` on result relation or not to use `joins` right in a scope etc.